# How to target a specific text field that follows a specific url using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

Currently I am trying to scrape a static html page using the Jsoup library in Java. I found a way to get exactly what I want but I'm not sure what to choose for my selector. Before, I was using CSS but the location of the text I want is not the same for every html page.

Therefore I was thinking of using this logic, the text that appears after a specific URL because the way the page is laid out is:

```
-Topic as a link-

Text field containing information related to Topic.
```

The HTML looks like this

```
<A NAME="Topic"></A> <A HREF="#TOPIC LiNK"><H2> TITLE OF TOPIC </H2></A>

<PRE><B leftmargin=150 marginwidth=100\>Content that I want to scrape</B></PRE>
```

I want to scrape everything in "Content that I want to scrape".

Comment: Ever looked at XPath? [The Documentation site has a tag for it](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xpath), and does just what you want (or at least if I understood it correctly).

Comment: the problem is jsoup doesn't support XPath, or least not that I know

Comment: Sorry, I was convinced it does...  Is JSoup a hard requirement? I used NekoHTML a while ago and that seems to support XPath... I'd recommend HtmlUnit too - but that is way too heavy and slow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example it looks like you trying to get text from `<PRE>` which is placed directly after `<A>`. In that case you can use `siblingA + siblingB` which will try to find `sibling B` *immediately* preceded by `sibling A` (you can find more information about selectors and examples at [official tutorial](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)  and [Selector documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)) .

So in your case `doc.select("a+pre").text()` should be enough.

You can add more details like specific URL of href attribute like `a[href=#TOPIC LiNK]`, or condition that `<A href=...>` also needs to be preceded by `<A name=..>` like

```
doc.select("a[name] + a + pre")
```